# How stop "onCreateView" in switch fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate

When i go from TabFrag3 on TabFrag1, TabFrag1 reload automatically all fragment.
I need to stop "onCreateView", when i switch from Tabfrag3 on TabFrag1.
How can I stop the function if it has already once been loaded?
I wish it worked just beginning.

Edit:

MainActivity:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

TabFragment1

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
        final ListView list= (ListView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        new function();//this function load json data
        return inflatedView;
}
```

This onCreateView charging data again and again...

Edit 2:
I found the solution here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/36518677/6910082

Comment: describe what you are trying to do and show some code.   There is nowhere near enough information to help.    If you are using a viewpager with multiple fragments then maybe try setOffscreenPageLimit()

Comment: Is that you want the pages not to refresh when navigating to tabs

Comment: Try to see the code. "Is that you want the pages not to refresh when navigating to tabs" => yes, i don't want the refresh of this fragment.

Comment: try adding `@Override public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
  }` in your `SectionsPagerAdapter`

Comment: I already have: "@Override public int getCount() { return 3; } => this code is autogenerate from Android Studio.

Comment: could be an error from your Activity. Mind to share your activity code?

Comment: For what reason do you not want to run onCreateView()? Interfering with the fragment life cycle seems inadvisable to me.

Comment: You're right, I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using add `instead` of `replace`. before you add the new `Fragment`, you should check if its already exiting in the `FragmentManager` if it does, hide current visible `Fragment` & show the other one, if it does not exists, then `add` it and hide the current visible `Fragment`.

for example:

```
@Nullable @Override public Fragment getFragmentByTag(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull String tag) {
    return fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);//returns fragment by its TAG.
}

@Nullable @Override public Fragment getVisibleFragment(@NonNull FragmentManager manager) {
    List<Fragment> fragments = manager.getFragments();
    if (fragments != null && !fragments.isEmpty()) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {
                Logger.e(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName(), fragment.isVisible());
                return fragment;//return current visible fragment to hide
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

then you should do something like :

```
Fragment currentVisibleFragment = getVisibleFragment(fragmentManager);
Fragment fragmentToAddOrShow = getFragmentByTag(fragmentManager, FormsListView.TAG);
```

then you should check if `fragmentToAddOrShow` is `not null` if it is then hide `currentVisibleFragment` and show `fragmentToAddOrShow` else hide `currentVisibleFragment` and add `fragmentToAddOrShow`

Comment: sorry i don't understand your solution. I try, but every time i return in fragment1 my fragment1 have visibility=visible and for this myfunction oncreateview restart all time.

Answer (score 0):

Using the hide() rather than go to the add () every time,just add() only in the first time